# how to get month name using current date as input in function

Tags: java, android, date

How do I create a function which take current date and return month name?
I have only date its not current date it can be any date like 2013/4/12 or 23/8/8.

Like `String monthName("2013/9/11");`
when call this function return the month name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should be fine.

It depends on the format of date.
If you try with February 1, 2011
it would work, just change this string "MMMM d, yyyy" according to your needs.
Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for all format patterns.

And also, months are 0 based, so if you want January to be 1, just return month + 1

```
   private static int getMonth(String date) throws ParseException{  
            Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(d);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            return month + 1;
    }
```

If you want month name try this

```
private static String getMonth(String date) throws ParseException{  
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(d);
    String monthName = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(cal.getTime());
    return monthName;
}
```

As I said, check web page I posted for all format patterns. If you want only 3 characters of month, use "MMM" instead of "MMMM"

Comment: also it will show wrong i put date 2013/08/14  this format "yyyy/MM/dd" function return me 7

Comment: because it is 0 base. If you want it to return 8, replace last line of code to return month + 1;

Comment: how to sho month name?? it retn number only:(

Comment: int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH+1); it will return 33

Comment: @user2762662 You got it?

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

I am contributing the modern answer.

```
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2013, Month.SEPTEMBER, 11) // Define the date
            .getMonth()                                        // Get the month
            .getDisplayName(                                   // Get the month name
                    TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE,                 // No abbreviation
                    Locale.ENGLISH));                          // In which language?
```

Output is:

> September

1. Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for a date.
2. Use `LocalDate.getMonth()` and `Month.getDisplayName()` to get the month name.
3. Avoid `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` used in the old answers from 2013. Those classes are poorly designed, troublesome and long outdated. The modern API is so much nicer to work with. Also avoid `switch`/`case` for this purpose since the month names are already built in, and using the library methods gives you clearer, terser and less error-prone code.

### Use LocalDate

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDate aDate = LocalDate.of(2013, Month.SEPTEMBER, 11); // 2013/9/11
    LocalDate anotherDate = LocalDate.of(2023, 8, 8); // 23/8/8
```

If you are getting the date as string input, parse the string using a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u/M/d");
    String stringInput = "2013/4/12";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(stringInput, dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

> 2013-04-12

### Use LocalDate.getMonth() and Month.getDisplayName()

To get the month name you first need to decide in which language you want the month name. I am taking English as an example and still using `date` from the previous snippet:

```
    String monthName = date.getMonth()
            .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(monthName);
```

> April

Java knows the month names in a wealth of languages. If you want the month name in the user’s language, pass `Locale.getDefault()` as the second argument to `getDisplayName()`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code -

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int month =  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

So now you have month number, you can use switch case to get name for that month.

If your date is in string format use this-

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(d)
```

Comment: is not efficient way to use 12 time swtchcase  tell me function which return month name using date

Comment: `String[] months = new String[]{"January", "February", ...}; String monthName = months[month];`

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento but absolutely not needed in this case

Comment: Other way can be- `DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
        String[] months = dfs.getMonths();String monthName = months[month]`

Comment: Yeah but he's supposed to use resourced strings anyway so locating the `R.string.MONTH_NAME`'s in an array (`int[]`) is almost no memory and prettier code IMO. Both are viable, take your pick

Comment: @RobinKanters Yes Agree.Also 12 switch-case wont be a good choice, it will make code look worse.

Comment: @RobinKanters there's a difference between optimized and fast code and nice readable code (that is to some extend opinion based, I don't think a switch will look so workse). Dependent on the number of times it will execute the function per time it can be worse optimizing or not (like fulfilling an array with thousand of values), so its application dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to get current month by name:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatterMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
String currentMonth = formatterMonth.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Function to get any month by name using format 2013/9/11: (not tested)

```
private String monthName(String dateToCheck){
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    date = formatter.parse(dateToCheck);
    SimpleDateFormat formatterMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    return formatterMonth.format(new Date(date.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using a function like this:

```
public String getDate(String startDate) throws ParseException {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = sdf.parse(startDate);
        sdf.applyPattern("MMMM dd, YYYY"); //this gives output as=> "Month date, year"
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return sdf.format(d);
}
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score -3):

You can obtain the "number" of the month as described in the other answer and then you could simply use a switch to obtain a name.
Example:

```
switch(month) {
case 0:
   your name is January
   break;
...
}
```

P.S. I think months are zero-based but I'm not 100% sure...